# Bug with height attribute of position absolute div in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-position

When I try to run the following

```
<body>
<div style="width: 400px;height: 1px;background-color: red;position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 0"></div>
</body>
```

It doesn't understand the height of my div in IE6 (also in 5.5).

Is this known bug? And how can I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't understand"? is the div too high? is it not visible? what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `font-size:0;line-height:0;` as well

Answer (score 2):

It won't create a height/width on it until there's something inside the div.  Try adding `&nbsp;` (or any other text) inside the div to get it to adjust properly.